# How to color a cell in Excel using a formula?

Tags: excel, formula

I want to do something like:

```
=iif(A1>10,backcolor = black,backcolor = green)
```

I want a formula not a wizard.

Comment: Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a formula, you should go with conditional formatting.
Select the appropriate column and go to **Home -> Conditional formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules.** Afterwards you can define the criteria, and which color the cell should become.

For a more extensive explanation, visit the following link. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

**EDIT:**

As far as I am aware of, changing the color of a cell is impossible using a formula. Should someone know how to do it, please post! In the meanwhile, this is a small routine on how to change the color to green using VBA.

```
Private Sub changecolor()
Dim i As Long: i = 1
 Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
Do Until i = LastRow
    With Range("A" & i)
        If .Value > 10 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        End If
    End With
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

**Note:** <s>This formula should take around 3~6 seconds per 100k rows, which could be rather slow, depending on the application.</s> After running a small test I found the following runtimes:

```
164269ms for 1000000 records with 45,4% coloured : ~16.4s/100k records
349193ms for 1000000 records with 100% coloured : ~34.9s/100k records
9016ms for 1000000 records with 0% coloured : ~0.9s/100k records
```

It seems using `Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex` ups the time with a whopping 34s/100k records! If someone knows a better way, feel free to enlighten us!

Comment: i wanna to use formula not conditional formatting . because i need to make it via MVC ( using c# )

Comment: Hmm as far as I'm aware of, you can't change the color of a cell using a formula. You can use VBA with `cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xx`, but I don't know if that's of any help to you, when using MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula in conjunction with an **Event Macro**.   Pick a cell, say **B2** and enter the formula:

```
=IF(A1>10,"black","green")
```

Then format **B2** Custom **;;;**
This will hide the displayed text.
Then place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Range("B2")
        If .Value = "green" Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Else
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The macro will run every time the worksheet is re-calculated.  It will exame the text in **B2** (*even though the text is not visible*) and adjust the backgound color accordingly.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**